# Typescript discriminated union parameter types - one param type dependant on another

Tags: typescript, types, switch-statement, discriminated-union

I'm trying to type a function that can take `template` and `params` parameters, where `params` is a union type that should get inferred by narrowing the type from the type of `template`.

Here is the code:

```js
enum Template {
  TEMPLATE_1,
  TEMPLATE_2,
}

type CreateTemplate1Params = {
  x: string,
  y: string,
  z: string,
}

type CreateTemplate2Params = {
  y: string,
}

type TemplateCreateParamsMap = {
  [Template.TEMPLATE_1]: CreateTemplate1Params,
  [Template.TEMPLATE_2]: CreateTemplate2Params,
}

const createTemplate1 = (params: CreateTemplate1Params) => {
  return
}

const createTemplate2 = (params: CreateTemplate2Params) => {
  return
}

const sendTemplate = <T extends keyof TemplateCreateParamsMap>(
  { template, params }: { template: T, params: TemplateCreateParamsMap[T] }
) => {
  switch (template) {
    case Template.TEMPLATE_1:
      // This isn't working - type of 'params' isn't being inferred properly
      // Type 'CreateTemplate2Params' is missing the following properties from type 'CreateTemplate1Params': x, z
      createTemplate1(params);
      break;
    case Template.TEMPLATE_2:
      createTemplate2(params);
      break;
    default:
      return
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong and why isn't the type of params being narrowed to the correct `CreateTemplateXParams` in the `sendTemplate` function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `{ template: T, params: TemplateCreateParamsMap[T] }` does not create a discriminated union. Instead, it gives us this type:

```
{
    template: keyof TemplateCreateParamsMap;
    params: CreateTemplate1Params | CreateTemplate2Params;
}
```

To create a discriminated union, you may use [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types):

```
const sendTemplate = <T extends keyof TemplateCreateParamsMap>(
  { template, params }: T extends T ? { template: T, params: TemplateCreateParamsMap[T] } : never
) => {
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAKsEAcA2BDALsKBvAsAKClgFEBZABQBkBBGIgfQEYAafQ2862ugJhbwF98+NAE8EmAMIAnYOmBxEqDAzIopKCAGcoAXmysoADwBcUTWikBLEAHM+hEafNXb9qAC8nF63fyC8wmKSMnIKyHLcqupauvoEUI5m3q5+Qnii4rDw4RjSshhRGpokKAixuPEA2mFKwAB07JQ09AwAuqZ5odm1KmpFbtXdcg2kTVzc7VCdGDURhVp8-vgAxgD2IOZQyyEzQ8qxABQIfVodO-J7wL3RmgCUugB8cYQyaGBSIKkBeGsbaFvnWYYbiHY43M75C6KOYnO6PZ5QV7vT4CNK-TaaUAAEyBmD0AB4YFBgIYMCAsdoANbAESrABmWWhuXO82KpQeBwMWCgGCZwCYUDBRSg-FMRJJZIpsCgAH5sDzLmKBULToycsBpsBWSUENVWiKoKYQMAAG7AKT4e46J4VQiaADuljQywAFlADrz1fdbYQtihMWraiMOM1GMYDL6AZDcQwjrDbgBuCO+gBGIUpSfihGW-swuODY3o3HDWd922jl24cZuieThDTsgzyaxwDpKDASDQJcjL2Abw+Bn8-CAA)

Comment: +1, interesting, didn't understand "why" it doesn't work as is though.. could you shed some light on it if you know? thanks!

Comment: @vr. thank you for your answer - super helpful!

@tanmay after doing some reading on distributive conditional types, my best guess would be: the typescript compiler runs statically, so regarding my original code, the compiler will try to infer every possible type of the `template` and `params` properties **at the point of type declaration**. So typescript outputs the type in the first part of @vr.'s answer (`template` and `params` are independent ahead of their declaration).

Comment: So in order to *distribute* the type of the entire object across its consumers, you have to let Typescript know that it should do so. Furthermore, because Typescript applies the conditional type to *each member of a union*, we can infer that the opposite is also true (when we don't use a condition) - Typescript will try to produce the least verbose type where possible (an object containing a union typed parameter, rather than a union of objects where one parameter type differs)